Is there a way to have a measure change to a blank value if it is being filtered?
I have an odd situation where a year over year sales measure will not be accurate when filtering by location because my company changed how they gave credit for ecomm/website sales.  The YOY sales is correct at a total company level, but when the table is filtered by location, it will given an inaccurate YOY sales number.
I want the measure to return blank if the location filter is used. Is that possible?
I tried
YOY Sales Growth blank filter = IF(ISFILTERED(Query1[net_sales]),BLANK(), [YOY Sales Growth])
But it continued to show values which were incorrect when I'd like it to just be blank.

Shouldn't you test the location, not the net_sales?
